# Is there any way to check whether any two numbers are equal from a set of three numbers in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I'm stuck at this point!

Let us consider three numbers `a,b,c` and
`a=2,b=100,c=2`

I want to print the numbers that are equals to each other. say `a and c equal to each other` from the example.
Is there any efficient method to achieve this through c++ ?. I don't want to use the relational operators with an if-else ladder.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What are the requirements for this assignment? What are the limitations? Please copy-paste the full assignment text into your question.

Comment: How are the numbers stored/passed? As regular variables (the post suggests this, but is not explicit about this), some container, a tuple, parameter pack....?

Comment: *Is there any efficient method to achieve this through c++ ?.* - -What would you do if the answer to that question was "no"?  Of course there are "efficient methods".  The second thing -- three numbers is nothing.  Ask about a thousand or a million numbers, then that's worthwhile trying to figure out an efficient method.

Comment: With *exactly* three numbers your unwanted if/else chain most likely is most efficient variant. There are only three of these checks necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`set`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) container and check return value of [`insert`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/) operation. You should also use some container like [`vector`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) to check values iteratively:

```
std::vector<int> numbers{2, 100, 2};
std::set<int> set;

for (const auto number : numbers)
{
    if (!set.insert(number).second)
    {
        std::cout << number << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `set::insert` is better.

Comment: *'Is there any efficient method'* – I doubt about efficiency compared to trivial solution...

Comment: But OP needs to know which value is duplicated: "I want to print the numbers that are equals to each other", so SET is not enough.

Comment: @Aconcagua Reading question I assumed that by efficiency OP meant less/more readable code.

Comment: @ufok I think the idea is to insert element iteratively. When the size doesn't change, the element was not unique and you can print it. However, it would be good to have the exact idea clarified in the answer.

Comment: @Aconcagua  O(nlogn) is good enough IMHO. Ofc, if the min and the max of inputs are limited, we can use some other algorithms of O(n).

Comment: @Yves There is a *fix* limited number of input, so *any* algorithm is O(1) anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
int a = 2, b = 100, c = 2;

int ans = (a + b + c) - (a ^ b ^ c);

cout << ans / 2 << endl;
```

Comment: Is there a name or description of this algorithm?

Comment: And what is the result? for `a=4, b=100, c=2` it prints `4`: https://godbolt.org/z/o6Eoqzshj

Comment: I assumed one of them is equal, What should be print if there is no equal. We can handle that as well. Like we can print 0

Comment: I used this method but it has some corner cases.
Working of the method is like this
for a=2,b=100,c=2
a+b+c=104 and the rest is xor operation . it gives the number which is distinct from the three numbers. 
here 2^100^2 = 100 since 2^2=0 and 0^100=100
so the answer is 104-100 = 4 and 4/2=2 .which is both a and c.